# How to insert one Cell into the first section of UITableView Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have created a UITableView with two sections. Now I am trying to populate one section. When I do action, my program populates both sections at the same time with the same text. What I am trying to do is to populate the first section, and then eventually move one of the cell from Section 1 to Section 2. So far I got here:

```
extension ListVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    randomCount = notes.count
    return notes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomNoteCell.reuseId) as! CustomNoteCell
    cell.set(with: notes[indexPath.row])
    return cell

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section < sections.count {
        return sections[section]
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

I believe it needs to happen in cellForRowAt but I have no clue how to specify section. Any help and clues appreciated. Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code of  `numberOfRowInSection` to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 { //first section
        randomCount = notes.count
        return notes.count
    }else{
    return 0
    }
}
```